# Week number based on timestamp with Go

Tags: go, time

I am trying to get the week number based on the timestamp using GoLang.

ts is a int64 and converted

```
tm := time.UTUnix(ts, 0)
year := tm.Year()
week_nb := ???
```

for history ts has been generated using:

```
ts := time.Now().UTC().Unix()
```

I sent it to a gRPC based server and the server translate it to week number and year.

Any body knows who to convert a ts to a weeknumber ? time library already allow me to get the year but not the week

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [func (Time) ISOWeek](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.ISOWeek)
>
> ```
> func (t Time) ISOWeek() (year, week int)
> ```
>
> ISOWeek returns the ISO 8601 year and week number in which t occurs.
>   Week ranges from 1 to 53. Jan 01 to Jan 03 of year n might belong to
>   week 52 or 53 of year n-1, and Dec 29 to Dec 31 might belong to week 1
>   of year n+1.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tn := time.Now().UTC()
    fmt.Println(tn)
    year, week := tn.ISOWeek()
    fmt.Println(year, week)

    ts := time.Now().UTC().Unix()
    tn = time.Unix(ts, 0)
    fmt.Println(tn)
    year, week = tn.ISOWeek()
    fmt.Println(year, week)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/CjfPscwYXf

Output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009 46
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009 46
```